# AutoMapper - merging a list of dtos and model into another dto

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following two models:

```
public class Employee
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string DisplayName { get; set; }
   public int CompanyId {get; set;}
}

public class Company
{
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; } 
}
```

and I want to map them to the following:

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyProfileDto
{
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; } 
   public List<EmployeeDto> Employees { get; set; } 
}
```

How would I do this using automapper? I can currently get Employee to map to EmployeeDto and Company to map to CompanyProfileDto but getting the List to be added is where I'm struggling.
Also, what would the mapping code be?

Current mapping profile:

```
CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>();
CreateMap<Company, CompanyProfileDto>()
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: In your business model, there is no relationship between the Employee and Company entities. In this case, how could AutoMapper retrieve a list of employees from a specific company?

Comment: How about if CompanyId was present in both Employee and Company?

Comment: `do this using automapper?` don't use Automapper? That's simply not what it is for. It's certainly not an ORM or data access driver and isn't meant to perform complex transformations. Only mappings based on conventions. If you use an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate, the ORM itself can load related entities and give you a `Company` with a `List<Employee> Employees` property

Comment: You should check [AutoMapper's Design Philosophy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/) . From the `Philosophy` section: *AutoMapper works because it enforces a convention. It assumes that your destination types are a subset of the source type. It assumes that everything on your destination type is meant to be mapped. It assumes that the destination member names follow the exact name of the source type. It assumes that you want to flatten complex models into simple ones.* `CompanyProfileDto` isn't one of those cases

Answer (score 1):

You can add the list of `Employees` to `Company`:

```
   public class Company
{
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; } 
   public List<Employee> Employees{get;set;

}
```

AutoMapper maps `List<Employee>` to `List<EmployeeDto>` automatically.

Also, you can use `Tuple` mapping instead as follows:

Add a new mapping profile like this:

```
           CreateMap<(Company, List<Employee>), CompanyProfileDto>()
            .ForMember(p => p.Employees, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.Item2))
            .ForMember(p => p.CompanyName, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.Item1.CompanyName))
            .ForMember(p=>p.CompanyId,config=>config.MapFrom(src=>src.Item1.CompanyId));
```

And map tuple of company and list of employees as follows:

```
var companyProfileDto=  _mapper.Map<CompanyProfileDto>((company, employees));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add the list of Employees to company as Employee and Company are two separate database tables and I can't change that structure. How would I do it using Tuple mapping?

Comment: Ok, Add new Mapping profile like this 

 `CreateMap<(Company, List<Employee>), CompanyProfileDto>()
                .ForMember(p => p.Employees, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.Item2))
                .ForMember(p => p.CompanyName, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.Item1.CompanyName))
                .ForMember(p=>p.CompanyId,config=>config.MapFrom(src=>src.Item1.CompanyId));
`
and map tuple of company and list of employees as follows:

`var companyProfileDto=  _mapper.Map<CompanyProfileDto>((company, employees));`
I tried this, It worked.

Comment: `two separate database tables` why not combine them then in your ORM? What are you using to query the database? EF Core? Dapper? Raw SQL? AutoMapper is meant to remove repetitive but simple, convention-based mappings, not transformations.